# Python: string & list re.sub comparison

Tags: python, regex

The string

```
txt = "this is a red house"
```

has come into existence. And then there is a list

```
patterns = ["thi", "a r", "use"]
```

with some matches for it.

The plan was to use `a = re.sub("".join(patterns), "".join(patterns) + "^", txt)`, which i hoped would return as ***thi^s is a r^ed house^***. Not so much – it just prints *the string* again. If `re.search` is used instead, it actually returns `None`, so the reason is that `re.sub` doesn’t find anything, simply returning the string.

I was ready to pull the plug on this, thinking that `re.sub` just can’t be used the way i thought it could, and then i accidentally tried it inside a simple loop:

```
for i in patterns:
    a = re.sub(i, i + "^", txt)
    print(a)
```

And suddenly it (almost) worked: ***thi^s is a red house*** [\n] ***this is a r^ed house*** [\n] ***this is a red house^***. Now i can’t just let it go. What is going on?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I would first start by figuring out what a working regex should look like before constructing it dynamically. Your call to `re.sub` produces the original input because your constructed regex doesn't match anything, so nothing is replaced.

Comment: You see, that’s what i thought. And then it matched in the loop. If constructed regex doesn’t match anything, why does it work there?

Comment: Because in your first call to `re.sub`, your regex is `thia ruse`. In your other calls within the loop, you look for `thi`, `a r`, and then `use`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop can be fixed completely if you replace `a` with `txt`:

```
for i in patterns:
    txt = re.sub(i, i + "^", txt)
    print(txt)
```

That way, you actually modify the text incrementally instead of performing each substitution on the original text and discarding the result:

```
this is a red house
thi^s is a red house
thi^s is a r^ed house
thi^s is a r^ed house^
```

Since you're not really using a regular expression in `re.sub()`, it'd be easier to just use `str.replace`:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    txt = txt.replace(pattern, pattern + '^')
```

If you actually want to use regular expressions, you'd have to do something like this:

```
patterns_regex = '(' + '|'.join(patterns) + ')'  # ['a', 'b'] -> '(a|b)'
print(re.sub(patterns_regex, r'\1^', txt)
```

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the result you're looking for:

```
txt = "this is a red house"
patterns = ["thi", "a r", "use"]

for s in patterns:
    txt = re.sub(s,s+'^',txt)
print(txt)
```

First, your print statement is inside the loop, hence the duplicate strings.

Second, your *re.sub(...)* is returning the changes to *'txt'* for each pass through the loop. If you wish to *accumulate* the changes you need to assign the results back to *'txt'*. Otherwise you will only see the latest substitution assigned to *'a'*.

Third,  *"".join(patterns)*  results in a string *"thia ruse"* which will not match any part of *'txt'*.

I hope this helps.  Regular expressions are discipline by themselves.  I've been using them since the 80's and still need to check the Docs. Keep going!

Answer (score 1):

Join your patterns together with `|`, then use a function as the replacement argument of `re.sub()`:

```
regex = re.compile("|".join([f"({p})" for p in patterns]))
regex.sub(lambda m: m.string[m.start():m.end()]+"^", txt)

# 'thi^s is a r^ed house^'
```

Note: If you don't want to use `re.compile()`, you can do it all in one line with:

```
re.sub("|".join([f"({p})" for p in patterns]), 
       lambda m: m.string[m.start():m.end()]+"^", 
       txt)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the substitutions at each iteration of your `for` loop.  Try reassigning the substituted value back to `txt`.

```
import re

txt = "this is a red house"
patterns = ["thi", "a r", "use"]

for i in patterns:
    txt = re.sub(i, i + "^", txt)
print(txt)
# prints:
thi^s is a r^ed house^
```